# How to make a button appear with material design

Tags: button, polymer, material-design, floating-action-button

How to make a button appear like in [Topeka](https://github.com/Polymer/topeka-elements/blob/master/topeka-quizzes.css) ? It should also hide when a parent is animating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this css:

```
:host(:not([animate])) paper-fab {
transition: transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 500ms, background-color 500ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
transform: scale(1);
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
:host([animate]) paper-fab {
visibility: hidden;
transition: transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 500ms, background-color 500ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
transform: scale(0);
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

Comment: Asked and answered by yourself in a flash! :D